# socks 5 proxy in centos 7

Tags: centos, vps, socks5-proxy

I want to run socks5 proxy server on centos7

Dante is for Debian

squid can not handle socks proxy

ss5 is too slow(almost do not work)

any good opensource socks5 proxy for centos7?

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you strictly want Socks5? If not, then Shadowsocks is a good option.

Comment: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ghettoforge-plus-x86_64/dante-1.4.1-176.9.x86_64.rpm.html